# Storing data from SQLite to MySQL Server

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I am writing code to send data from `SQLite` database to `MYSQL server` database, and whenever i do tap on `sync data` button, getting toast `"DB Sync completed"` as given in my program, but not getting data on server... i am using [this](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/) link

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
public void syncSQLiteMySQLDB(){
        //Create AsycHttpClient object
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList =  controller.getAllUsers();
        if(userList.size()!=0){
            if(controller.dbSyncCount() != 0){
                prgDialog.show();
                params.put("usersJSON", controller.composeJSONfromSQLite());
                client.post("http://10.0.2.2/sqlitemysqlsync/insertuser.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        System.out.println(response);
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        try {
                            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                            System.out.println(arr.length());
                            for(int i=0; i<arr.length();i++){
                                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)arr.get(i);
                                System.out.println(obj.get("id"));
                                System.out.println(obj.get("status"));
                                controller.updateSyncStatus(obj.get("id").toString(),obj.get("status").toString());
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DB Sync completed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occured [Server's JSON response might be invalid]!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,
                        String content) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        if(statusCode == 404){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else if(statusCode == 500){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data in SQLite DB, please do enter User name to perform Sync action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

**DBController.java:-**

```
public class DBController  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBController(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext, "androidsqlite.db", null, 1);
    }
    //Creates Table
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query;
        query = "CREATE TABLE users ( userId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, userName TEXT, udpateStatus TEXT)";
        database.execSQL(query);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
        String query;
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users";
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
    }
    /**
     * Inserts User into SQLite DB
     * @param queryValues
     */
    public void insertUser(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("userName", queryValues.get("userName"));
        values.put("udpateStatus", "no");
        database.insert("users", null, values);
        database.close();
    }

    /**
     * Get list of Users from SQLite DB as Array List
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllUsers() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
        wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM users";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("userId", cursor.getString(0));
                map.put("userName", cursor.getString(1));
                wordList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        database.close();
        return wordList;
    }

    /**
     * Compose JSON out of SQLite records
     * @return
     */
    public String composeJSONfromSQLite(){
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
        wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM users where udpateStatus = '"+"no"+"'";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("userId", cursor.getString(0));
                map.put("userName", cursor.getString(1));
                wordList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        database.close();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        //Use GSON to serialize Array List to JSON
        return gson.toJson(wordList);
    }

    /**
     * Get Sync status of SQLite
     * @return
     */
    public String getSyncStatus(){
        String msg = null;
        if(this.dbSyncCount() == 0){
            msg = "SQLite and Remote MySQL DBs are in Sync!";
        }else{
            msg = "DB Sync needed\n";
        }
        return msg;
    }

    /**
     * Get SQLite records that are yet to be Synced
     * @return
     */
    public int dbSyncCount(){
        int count = 0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM users where udpateStatus = '"+"no"+"'";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        count = cursor.getCount();
        database.close();
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Update Sync status against each User ID
     * @param id
     * @param status
     */
    public void updateSyncStatus(String id, String status){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();    
        String updateQuery = "Update users set udpateStatus = '"+ status +"' where userId="+"'"+ id +"'";
        Log.d("query",updateQuery);     
        database.execSQL(updateQuery);
        database.close();
    }
}
```

What could be the reason ? why i am not getting data on mysql server ?

**Logcat:**

```
11-18 05:07:50.574: I/System.out(1174): [{"id":"1","status":"no"},{"id":"2","status":"no"}]
11-18 05:07:50.584: I/System.out(1174): 2
11-18 05:07:50.584: I/System.out(1174): 1
11-18 05:07:50.584: I/System.out(1174): no
11-18 05:07:50.634: D/query(1174): Update users set udpateStatus = 'no' where userId='1'
11-18 05:07:50.694: I/System.out(1174): 2
11-18 05:07:50.694: I/System.out(1174): no
11-18 05:07:50.754: D/query(1174): Update users set udpateStatus = 'no' where userId='2'
```

Comment: Try to write a small test or main that writes some hard-coded data first, to see that your write code works. afterwards print out what you have red from the SQLite DB and see that it is not empty

Comment: does  onSuccess(String response) {
                        System.out.println(response); .. print the correct values?